# On the contravariant functor of preorders and its representability

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, order-theory

$$
\newcommand{op}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
\newcommand{cat}[1]{\op{#1}}
\newcommand{hom}[1][2]{\cat{Hom}(#1,#2)}
$$

On what at this point is becoming a series, I'm going through an exercise of Emily Riehl's Category Theory in Context,

> Exercise 2.4.v. Define a contravariant functor $F: \cat{Set}^{op} \rightarrow \cat{Set}$ that carries a set to the set
>   of preorders on it. What is its category of elements? Is $F$ representable?

I've defined this functor as

$$
\mathfrak{P} : \cat{Set}^{op} \longrightarrow \cat{Set} \\
X \longmapsto \mathfrak{P}(X) \\
(f:X \to Y) \mapsto \mathfrak{P}(f)
$$
with $\mathfrak{P}(X) = \{\leq  \ \subseteq  \ X \times X : \leq \text{ is a preorder on } X\}$ and, given a function $f: X \to Y$,

$$
(x,y) \in \mathfrak{P}(f)(\leq) \iff f(x) \leq f(y)
$$

If this is the correct/usual construction of such functor then its category of elements has objects as sets with a fixed preorder $(X, \leq )$ and morphisms as functions that behave as previously described, i.e. $f : (X,\leq) \rightarrow (Y, \leq')$ is a morphism in $\int \mathfrak{P}$ if and only if

$$
x \leq x' \iff f(x) \leq f(x') \quad (\forall x, x' \in X)
$$

Now, as is proven in this exercises' chapter, a contravariant functor is representable if and only if its category of elements has a terminal object. In this case, this means that $\mathfrak{P}$ would be representable if and only if there exists a set $X_F$ equipped with a preorder $\preceq$ so that, for any preordered set $(X,\leq)$, there exists a unique function $f : X \rightarrow X_F$ such that

$$
x \leq x' \iff f(x) \preceq f(x') \quad (\forall x,x' \in X)
$$

My intuition is that this will not happen, although I am not fully convinced about my (apparent) proof, which goes as follows: suppose that such a final object $(X_F, \preceq)$ exists. Therefore, there should exist a unique function $s : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow X_F$ that defines the usual order on $\mathbb{N}$ and thus $s(\mathbb{N})$ gives a countably infinite chain on $X_F$. In particular, there exist distinct elements $x \preceq x' \preceq x''$ in $X_F$.

However, this contradicts the unicity of morphisms towards $X_F$ in the case of $T = \{1,2\}$ with the usual order, since the functions

$$
f_1: T \rightarrow X_F \\
  1 \mapsto x \\
  2 \mapsto x'\\
$$

$$
f_2: T \rightarrow X_F \\
  1 \mapsto x' \\
  2 \mapsto x''\\
$$

both verify $y \leq y' \iff f_i(y) \leq f_i(y') \ (\forall y,y' \in T)$.

Have I missed something along the way? I had a strong intuition about $\mathfrak{P}$ being representable when I started thinking about this, but now I am leaning towards a negative answer.

Comment: I haven't checked your solution to "is it representable ?" but here's a quick answer : a representable functor preserves limits, so here it should send colimits in $Set$ to limits in $Set$: does it send a coproduct to a product ? in more intuitive words, is a preorder on $X\coprod Y$ determined by its restrictions to $X$ and $Y$ ?

Comment: @Max well, I presume not, since relations in between the elements of $X$ and $Y$ cannot be reconstructed from the individual restrictions. I am barely familiar with (co) products, and (co) limits are actually treated on the next chapter of Riehl's book which I haven't started, so even though I intuitively see what you mean I have no tools yet to formalize it. If you have the time, I would really appreciate if you could give my solution a read to see if it is correct, and as always, thanks a lot for you time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that argument looks good. You could just use the order $0<1<2$, instead of going all the way to $\mathbb{N}$.